# Open MPI: using bind-to-core while oversubscribing

Tags: mpi, openmpi

My question is that is it possible to use `--bind-to-core` flag when oversubscribing? I am using OPEN MPI version 1.5.4 and trying oversubscribe with a factor of 2 (32 processes on 16 cores) using:

```
mpirun --bind-to-core --bynode --npersocket 32 --mca mpi_yield_when_idle 1 -n 32 ./$prog
```

But it returns me an error:

```
32 total processes failed to start
```

However, if I don't use `--bind-to-core` everything works fine. What's the problem here? Is it possible to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-npersocket` option activates `--bind-to-socket` and this conflicts with `--bind-to-core`. You can probably get around it with writing a *rankfile* - very similar to a hostfile but it also contains binding information for each rank. For example, to bind 4 processes to 2 cores on host `localhost`, the following rankfile could be used:

```
rank 0=localhost slot=0
rank 1=localhost slot=0
rank 2=localhost slot=1
rank 3=localhost slot=1
```

Rankfiles are provided to `mpiexec` with the `--rankfile` option. Consult the [Open MPI documentation](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man1/mpiexec.1.php#sect9) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another way to check the bindings to confirm the allocation? As for me --report-bindings isn't providing any output regarding the process bindings

Comment: Are you by any chance redirecting the standard error stream to `/dev/null`?

Comment: I don't think that it is being redirected there. I am using LSF submission system for my jobs and I get other errors and outputs in the log file that I am redirecting the output to.